# SSL reverse-proxy

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy

Please recommend reverse SSL proxy. Need to receive HTTPS traffic at 443 port on Load balancer and then forward it to 443 port on web servers.

HAProxy doesn't support HTTPS
Varnish as well
Stunnel stucks here

I see two ways: trying to use iptables or check if nginx fit our requirements.

Please advice what  do you guys using to balance SSL traffic.

Answer (score 4):

Nginx can do this for you and more. 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy/

Answer (score 1):

F5 BigIP LTM's work great...but they aren't free...

Comment: it seems they have hardware decisioins only, isn't it?

Comment: Yep.  They work well though.

Comment: No, you can use the [Virtual Edition](https://www.f5.com/trial/big-ip-ltm-virtual-edition.php), however you lose a few things when you do this. First, the F5 hardware accelerates specific types of TCP traffic and secondly, they have a dedicated hardware SSL add-in card. When trying to encrypt and decrypt SSL traffic, this takes a large amount of load off of the software/processor that you don't get with Virtual Edition.

Answer (score 1):

HAProxy isn´t a reverse proxy, if you only need the load balancer feature you can still use HAProxy, using mode tcp to Load balance to your SSL servers,

> haproxy (mode tcp) => ssl-servers

Or, you can use a nginx frontent to 'remove' the ssl, and then forward it to your webservers in plain-text...

> nginx(ssl)=>haproxy(mode http)=>web-servers

BTW, if you add varnish (after remove the ssl encryption), verify if you aplication is sending the correct Cache-Control headers, so your reverse proxy only caches static contents, and not the private stuff. Take a look on http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9